# working with reflection and stream reader in c sharp

Tags: c#

i have a question on reflection in c sharp..this is my question

1) define class MyClass with different fields with different accessors(private, public, protected) also methods with different argument set and return types

2) define MyTestClass which contains method, that do the following: print method names for spicified class name, where methods contain string arguments, class name is string value.  Call some method of class, and put arguments to method, arguments should read from text file(name of class and name of method is arguments of method

i have answered the question but i am having a problem,i can not read from the text file when i run the program inside the text file there is a double number and an integer but its not showing on the console
this is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;

class MyClass
{
    private int i;
    public double d;
    private string s;
    public bool b;
    public MyClass()
    {
        i = 1;
        d = 0.1;
        s = "1";
        b = true;
    }
    public void Method0()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method with no arguments, no return value.");
    }
    private int Method1(int arg0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The method returns int, int gets.");
        return arg0;
    }
    private double Method2(int arg0, double arg1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method returns a double, taking int and double.");
        return arg1 * arg0;
    }
    public bool Method3(string arg0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method returns a bool, accepts string");
        return arg0.Length>10;
    }
    public bool Method3(string arg0,string arg1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The method takes two arguments string.");
        return arg0 == arg1;
    }
    public static char Method4(string arg0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method returns a char, accepts string. .");
        return arg0[1];
    }
    public void Method5(int arg0, double arg1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("arg1 = {0} arg2 = {1}.",arg0,arg1);
    }
}

class MyTestClass
{
    public static string[] GetMethodsWithStrParams(string className)
    {
        var t = Type.GetType(className);
        List<string> res = new List<string>();
        foreach (var method in t.GetMethods())
        {
            foreach (var param in method.GetParameters())
            {
                if (param.ParameterType == typeof(string))
                {
                    res.Add(method.Name);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return res.ToArray();
    }
    public static void InvokeMethod(string className, string methodName, string fileName)
    {
        var t = Type.GetType(className);
        using (StreamReader f = new StreamReader("params.txt"))
        {
            t.GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(new object[] { }),
                                           new object[] { f.ReadLine() });
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name = "MyClass";

        foreach (var x in MyTestClass.GetMethodsWithStrParams(name))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }

        MyTestClass.InvokeMethod("MyClass", "Method4", "params.txt");

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

this is the output when i run the program

```
method3
method3
method4
Method returns a char, accepts string. .
```

but inside params.txt there is

```
10 1.5
```

Comment: You need to show us what the output is. As it stands it is hard to understand the problem.

Comment: ok let me edit it and show u the output

Comment: Your code works fine and if you write `Console.WriteLine(arg0);` in `Method4` you will recieve `10 1.5` in console. Please, tell us what do you want in your output.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly thanks i guess that was the missing piece

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

Split the reflection part into two: 1) the construction of the object; 2) the invoke of the method. This makes the code a bit clearer and you could maybe re-use the object for the invoke of a next method.

The `f.ReadLine()` returns a single string. It does not automatically split this into separate arguments. The `new object[] { f.ReadLine() }` gives an object-array with a *single* string value.
You will need to split that line yourself on some separator into separate values. Then you will need to convert those separate strings into the parameter-types your method needs.

Answer (score 0):

I run your code in visual Studio and the only problem I had was the file name. the rest seemed to work in principle. is the file params.txt definitely in executable folder? If not you will need to provide full path.

```
MyTestClass.InvokeMethod("MyClass", "Method4", "c:\\params.txt");
```

Another question I have is? does MyClass exist within a namespace? If so you will need to use namespace to return Type object:

```
MyTestClass.InvokeMethod("MyNamespace.MyClass", "Method4", "c:\\params.txt");
```

Also I just noticed that despite the fact that method InvokeMethod accepts filename as argument it has got a hard-coded filename. It therefore ignores filename passed by calling code (in main method).